# Animate rotated objects with Raphaël.js

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm my current project I need to draw robots and move them around.
A robot is composed of a circle and a box which shows the current orientation of the robot.

My problem is that I when I animate them, the orientation box moves in a strange way because of its rotation...

Here's what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/zmunB/

Thanks for your help.

Balzard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cordesmj/2XA2D/) shows another option. It may not be quite as elegant as rajkamal's solution, but it may be easier to understand if you are not used to working with matrices. You should be able to add features to it at will (notice the 'eye' I added).

Basically, I am just adding the features to a set, and applying the transformations to each element in the set. Kick off the animations by clicking the colored squares to the right. Note that 'Move relative' will make the set move in the direction it is 'looking'.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/apUvX/2/ , for transformed movements.
Here in "onAnimation" method of circle, we are transforming the circle's center coordinate to the 
rectangles coordinate system using `Matrix.x`,`Matrix.y` and assigning the result to the the x,y of the rectangle.